# Recorrer array asociativo con foreach en PHP

Tags: php

Quiero imprimir en un select el array colonias por medio de un foreach pero no me queda.

```
{
  "delegacion":"\u00c1lvaro Obreg\u00f3n",
  "estado":"Ciudad de M\u00e9xico",
  "region":"Centro",
  "colonias":[
    {"idcp":"27886","asentamiento":"Ampliaci\u00f3n El Capul\u00edn"},
    {"idcp":"27887","asentamiento":"Liberales de 1857"},
    {"idcp":"27888","asentamiento":"Bel\u00e9m de las Flores"},
    {"idcp":"27889","asentamiento":"El Capul\u00edn"}
  ]
}
```

Logre hacerlo con jQuery de la siguiente manera pero me lo piden en PHP.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.colonias.length; i++) {
  $('#colonias').append('<option value="' + data.colonias[i].idcp + '">' + data.colonias[i].asentamiento + '</option>');
}
```

Comment: "me lo piden en foreach"  te piden que cargues el select desde PHP (retornarías el select `html` con las opciones cargadas) o que realices el foreach en HTML cargandolo con jquery pero usando codigo php tambien?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) para crear un array o un objeto stdClass a partir de tu json.

La lectura, en caso de usar `json_decode` creando un stdClass sería muy simple.

Viendo tu código, al parecer querrías options con las colonias que hay en el JSON.

Para obtenerlo puedes hacer:

```
   $json='{
      "delegacion":"\u00c1lvaro Obreg\u00f3n",
      "estado":"Ciudad de M\u00e9xico",
      "region":"Centro",
      "colonias":[
        {"idcp":"27886","asentamiento":"Ampliaci\u00f3n El Capul\u00edn"},
        {"idcp":"27887","asentamiento":"Liberales de 1857"},
        {"idcp":"27888","asentamiento":"Bel\u00e9m de las Flores"},
        {"idcp":"27889","asentamiento":"El Capul\u00edn"}
      ]
    }';

  $myJson=json_decode($json);

$strHTML='<select id="colonias">'; //Si sólo quieres los option quita esto

foreach ($myJson->colonias as $k){
    $strHTML.='<option value="'.$k->idcp.'">'.$k->asentamiento.'</option>';
}

$strHTML.='</select>';            //Si sólo quieres los option quita esto

echo $strHTML;
```

### Resultado:

```html
    <select id="colonias">
    <option value="27886">
        Ampliación El Capulín
    </option>

    <option value="27887">
        Liberales de 1857
    </option>

    <option value="27888">
        Belém de las Flores
    </option>

    <option value="27889">
        El Capulín
    </option>
</select>
```

---

Respuesta anterior con más explicaciones...

```
<?php

$json='{
  "delegacion":"\u00c1lvaro Obreg\u00f3n",
  "estado":"Ciudad de M\u00e9xico",
  "region":"Centro",
  "colonias":[
    {"idcp":"27886","asentamiento":"Ampliaci\u00f3n El Capul\u00edn"},
    {"idcp":"27887","asentamiento":"Liberales de 1857"},
    {"idcp":"27888","asentamiento":"Bel\u00e9m de las Flores"},
    {"idcp":"27889","asentamiento":"El Capul\u00edn"}
  ]
}';

$myJson=json_decode($json);
print_r($myJson);

/*Leyendo datos*/
echo "DELEGACIÓN: ".$myJson->delegacion.PHP_EOL;
echo "ESTADO: ".$myJson->estado.PHP_EOL;
echo "REGIÓN: ".$myJson->region.PHP_EOL;

echo "COLONIAS: ".PHP_EOL;

foreach ($myJson->colonias as $k){
    echo "\t".$k->idcp." - ".$k->asentamiento.PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Aquí el `print_r($myJson);`  es sólo informativo, para ver lo que se crea.

Verás esto en pantalla:

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [delegacion] => Álvaro Obregón
    [estado] => Ciudad de México
    [region] => Centro
    [colonias] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idcp] => 27886
                    [asentamiento] => Ampliación El Capulín
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idcp] => 27887
                    [asentamiento] => Liberales de 1857
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idcp] => 27888
                    [asentamiento] => Belém de las Flores
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idcp] => 27889
                    [asentamiento] => El Capulín
                )

        )

)
```

### Resultado:

Lo que interesa es esto. El resultado final sería algo así:

```
DELEGACIÓN: Álvaro Obregón
ESTADO: Ciudad de México
REGIÓN: Centro
COLONIAS: 
    27886 - Ampliación El Capulín
    27887 - Liberales de 1857
    27888 - Belém de las Flores
    27889 - El Capulín
```

Comment: esta fue la solucion muchas gracias foreach ($myJson->colonias as $k){
    echo "\t".$k->idcp." - ".$k->asentamiento.PHP_EOL;
}

Comment: Me alegro @CarlosEnriqueGilGil. Por favor consulta [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien consteta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Si el problema ha sido resuelto por favor marca la respuesta  más adecuada como solución, de ese modo la pregunta no seguirá apareciendo como sin resolver.

Comment: listo me falto marcar la palomita perdon.

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas puedes poner más información para darte una respuesta más exacta, pero a grandes rasgos sería algo como esto:

```
<select>
<?php foreach($datos as $dato){ ?>
  <option><?php echo $dato->delegacion; ?></option>
  <option><?php echo $dato->estado; ?></option>
  <option><?php echo $dato->region; ?></option>
  <option><?php echo $dato->colonia; ?></option> 
<?php  }?>
</select>
```

Donde $datos es la variable que contiene la información de tu query a la BD.

Answer (score 0):

No me queda muy claro, pero si es a partit de un json(es lo que tienes ahi) lo ideal es con el each de jquery pero si te piden con foreach  seria

```
data.colonias.forEach(function(element) {
//inertas los options en el select
//puedes crearlos con jquery
// o js con createElement
});
```

Si es directo desde el php la respuesta de Alvaro vergara esta bien

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar  `json_decode`   y recorrer el arreglo:

```
<?php
$json =
'{
  "delegacion":"\u00c1lvaro Obreg\u00f3n",
  "estado":"Ciudad de M\u00e9xico",
  "region":"Centro",
  "colonias":[
    {"idcp":"27886","asentamiento":"Ampliaci\u00f3n El Capul\u00edn"},
    {"idcp":"27887","asentamiento":"Liberales de 1857"},
    {"idcp":"27888","asentamiento":"Bel\u00e9m de las Flores"},
    {"idcp":"27889","asentamiento":"El Capul\u00edn"}
  ]
}';

$jArray = json_decode($json);

$colonias = $jArray->colonias;

?>
<select>
<?php foreach ($colonias as  $key => $value) : ?>

  <option value="<?php echo $value->idcp; ?>"><?php echo $value->asentamiento; ?></option>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
```